# Como criar um array de matriz multidimensional em c++?

Tags: array, c++, array-multidimensional

Tenho uma matriz `float m2D[4][4]`. Para os fins do meu programa, preciso ao mesmo tempo que altero os valores nos componentes de `m2D` poder salvar o estado anterior a essa alteração. É basicamente a ideia de empilhar, contudo não sei como criar uma estrutura que possa conter n versões da minha matriz multidimensional `m2D`.

Uma ideia foi usar outra matriz multidimensional tal como `m3D[4][4][n]`, assim poderia fazer algo como:

`m3D[0][0][0] = m2D[0][0];`

`m3D[0][1][0] = m2D[1][0];`

...
Contudo, a terceira dimensão da matriz deveria variar conforme a necessidade de salvar o estado atual de `m2D` - algo que esse método não provê.

Outra possibilidade foi tentar usar o template `vector` para tentar criar um array de n versões de `m2D`, porém esbarro em não saber como criar um template de vector com o tipo de float[4][4].

Comment: Você pode armazenar toda a matriz na versão pré-alteração ou armazenar apenas o(s) elemento(s) que foi(ram) alterado(s). Talvez você queira alguma outra informação extra matriz, como por exemplo a data da alteração. Caso a quantidade de versões que irá guardar não seja predeterminada você pode criar uma estrutura dinâmica, como por exemplo uma lista encadeada de matrizes, onde cada elemento da lista seja uma estrutura composta de uma matriz e um ponteiro para a próxima ou anterior ou ambos. A solução mais adequada depende da utilização que irá fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderia ser de ajuda se você tivesse uma matriz tridimensional, sendo que o primeiro índice seria justamente uma espécie de indicador de histórico, enquanto que os outros dois índices seriam as linhas e colunas.

Desta forma você poderia ter uma função que receberia uma matriz base e uma matriz alvo além de um número de linha, um número de coluna e um valor do tipo da matriz, essa função poderia fazer a cópia dos dados da matriz base para a alvo e, ao fim, alterar o valor na célula desejada. Veja:

```
const int LIMITE = 4;

void mudar_celula(float matriz_anterior[LIMITE][LIMITE], float matriz_nova[LIMITE][LIMITE], int i, int j, float valor)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < LIMITE; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < LIMITE; j++)
            matriz_nova[i][j] = matriz_anterior[i][j];
    matriz_nova[i][j] = valor;
}
```

Lembre-se sempre de inicializar suas matrizes antes de usá-las, elas podem vir com lixos de memória.
Se você fosse trabalhar com `vector` seria interessante definir a matriz dentro de uma `struct`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

const int LIMITE = 4;

typedef struct matriz
{
    float matriz[LIMITE][LIMITE];
} MAT;

int main()
{
    std::vector<MAT> matrizes;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```